# Having problems installing Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

When I try to install Ruby on Rails via `gem install rails`,
I get the following error:

```
C:\Ruby193>gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing rails:
       ERROR: Failed to build gem nativ extension.

   C:/Ruby193/bin.ruby.exe -r ;/siteconf20150202-6216-3lwzut.rb extconf.rb creating MakeFile

make  clean
'make' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme executable ou un fichier de commandes.

'make' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme executable ou un fichier de commandes.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gem/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/json-1.8.2/gem_make.out
```

I've been unable to figure out the cause of the problem or a solution and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try updating RubyGems: `gem update --system 2.4.4`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this: http://railsinstaller.org/en

it's a new installation in easy way! 
I hope I was helpful

For problem in `gem install rails`try run this before:

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```

Comment: Sorry for answering that late. I dit that and everything went well until i try to run "rails server" which grants me a new error i cant understand